# Troubles while working with Ruby on Rails and databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I am new to RoR and trying to create my first app, I have setu up the environment in Rubymine IDE, and now want to create a database for the app. Previously I have been using SQLite studio for developing the database, or phpMyadmin for mysqli database. Now since rails uses sqlite3 database integration, or I could use mysql, my question is. Can I somehow import the database created in SQLite studio or MySQL Workbench to Rails app, or do I have to go and type database commands through command line on windows, which I was not using before for such purposes. I did not find any detailed informations on the web for this question. This is confusing me out?

Answer (score 0):

create a dump of the sample database.

```
sqlite3 sample.db .dump > dump.sql
```

import it into mysql

```
mysql -p -u root -h 127.0.0.1 test < dump.sql
```

it may work.